# Is this method for comparing whether two distributions have similar outliers studied in the literature?

Tags: distributions, statistical-significance, p-value, outliers

I am working on a project where I am trying to compare outliers from two different distributions. I came up with a natural seeming measurement, and I want to find out whether there's a name for it or any literature about it.

Here is the idea:

We have two distributions over $\mathbb{R}$, $C_1$ and $C_2$ with CDFs $F_1$ and $F_2$ respectively. We let $\alpha \in (0,1/2)$ be some parameter.

We let $g_i$ be a classifier defined by $g_i(x) = \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      1  &F_i(x) \geq 1 - \alpha \\ 
      -1  &F_i(x) \leq \alpha \\
0  &else
\end{array} 
\right.$

We let $C'_i$ be the distribution defined by conditioning $C_i$ to be in the $\alpha$th or not in the $1 - \alpha$th percentile. That is, if $p_i$ is the pdf of $C_i$, then the pdf of $C'_i$ is $p_i'(x) = \frac{1}{2 \alpha} p_i(x) 1_{ g_i(x) \not = 0 }$.

We define a measurement of the difference between $C_1$ and $C_2$ by $\frac{1}{2} ( \mathbb{P}_{x \sim C_1'}(g_1(x) \not = g_2(x)) + \mathbb{P}_{x \sim C_2}(g_1(x) \not = g_2(x)))$. Intuitively, the idea is that we pick $i \in \{1,2\}$ at random, and then draw an outlier from $C_i$, and calculate the probability that it is an outlier of the same type under $C_2$.

The statistic I'm using is given by taking samples from both distributions, say $x_i$ from $C_1$ for $i = 1, \ldots, N_1$ and $y_i$ from $C_2$ for $i = 1, \ldots, N_2$, and then calculating the obvious empirical of this formula. The empiricial version is obtained by using the empirical cdf $\hat{F}_i$ to define $\hat{g}_i$, and then using $\frac{1}{2} ( \frac{1}{N_1} \sum_{i 
= 1}^{N_1}1_{\hat{g}_1(x_i) \not = \hat{g}_2(x_i)} + \frac{1}{N_2} \sum_{i 
= 1}^{N_2}1_{\hat{g}_1(y_i) \not = \hat{g}_2(y_i)})$

Thanks!